# Is there a difference between JPY TONA and JPY TONAR?

Tags: libor, benchmark, libor-cessation, risk-free-rate, rfr

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TONAR) defines TONAR as "Tokyo Overnight Average Rate".

The official Bank of Jappan [website](https://www.boj.or.jp/en/finsys/libor/index.htm/) mentions TONA, rather than TONAR.

I suspect the two, TONAR and TONA, are in fact two terms referring to the same rate, but I just wanted to double check here: hoping for someone knowledgeable of the Japanese market to confirm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [document](https://www.nl.bk.mufg.jp/media/1252/what-are-the-replacement-benchmarks-and-which-ibors-are-changing-june-2020.pdf) from Japanese bank Mitsubishi UFJ states they are one and the same rate, see page 3 $-$ my emphasis:

> ***TONAR** (Tokyo Overnight Average Rate), the RFR for JPY **also called TONA**, is a pre-existing rate.*